# What do ‘All things delivered to Jesus by His Father’ include?

Tags: matthew

Matthew 11:27:- All things have been delivered to Me by My Father, and no one knows the Son except the Father. Nor does anyone know the Father except the Son, and the one to whom the Son wills to reveal Him.

Answer (score 2):

The teaching in Matt 11:27 is not unique:

- Matt 28:18 - Then Jesus came to them and said, “All **authority** in heaven and on earth has been given to Me.
- John 3:35 - The Father loves the Son and has placed **all things** in His hands.
- John 13:3 - Jesus knew that the Father had delivered **all things** into His hands, and that He had come from God and was returning to God.
- John 17:2 - For You granted Him **authority over all people**, so that He may give eternal life to all those You have given Him.
- 1 Cor 15:25 - For He must reign until He has put **all His enemies under His feet**.
- 1 Cor 15:27 - For “God has put **everything** under His feet.” ...
- Col 1:16, 17 - For in Him all things were created, things in heaven and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or authorities. All things were created through Him and for Him. He is before all things, and in Him **all things hold together**.
- Heb 1:8 - But about the Son He says: “**Your throne, O God, endures forever** and ever, and justice is the scepter of Your kingdom."
- Heb 1:13 - ... “Sit at My right hand until I make **Your enemies** a footstool for Your feet”
- Eph 1:19-22 - ... These are in accordance with the working of His mighty strength, which He exerted in Christ when He raised Him from the dead and seated Him at His right hand in the heavenly realms, far above **all rule and authority, power and dominion**, and every name that is named, not only in the present age but also in the one to come.
- Rev 11:15 - “The **kingdom of the world has become the kingdom of our Lord and of His Christ**, and He will reign forever and ever.”

Little wonder that Jesus could say:

- Matt 1:27 - All things have been entrusted to Me by My Father. ...

Note the comments of Barnes:

> **All things are delivered** ... It means that Christ has control over all things for the good of his church; that the government of the
> universe is committed to him "as Mediator," that he may redeem his
> people and guide them to glory, Ephesians 1:20-22.

Answer (score 0):

In some of the commentaries. these words are related to the immediate context; in this case, the context being the previous "Thou has hidden these things from the wise and understanding and revealed them to babes" (v25 RSV). Then "all things" would be the knowledge of all things (or at least all things relating to salvation), leading in turn to the statement at the end of the verse that "knowledge of the Father" also necessarily comes through the Son.

So R.T. France says in his commentary; "There are no secrets between Father and Son... "All things" refers here (in the light of vv25-26) to the knowledge they share." (p199).

A fuller answer would incorporate both angles; the immediate context and the usage in the rest of the Bible.

Answer (score 0):

I read this part as an obvious statement that is used to motivate his followers. Jesus is a monogeneous son [John 3:16]
So he just states the obvious that a [monogeneous] son gets all his talents from his father only.

What you have as "all things" in Greek Septuaginta LXX https://biblehub.com/interlinear/apostolic/matthew/11.htm is just one word πάντα - which does not specifically refer to *things* but just means "all". https://biblehub.com/greek/3956.htm

Also "no one knows" is οὐδείς and it can mean "knows nothing" as well as "no one knows"  https://biblehub.com/greek/3762.htm

So the 11:27 I would read as following:

*... All was handed over to me by my father. And a [monogeneous] son can not know anything were it not for the [genes] that came from father. Only a son would know his father and whoever the father decided to reveal that he is son.* (Biological genes and knowledge being both Information this is kind of a trivial statement too.)

Now, one could argue that a mother can know for sure who the father was. But here it was not the case. And anyway in a natural order of things it is impossible to know which sperm from millions did manage to inseminate the egg.